# Python Lottery Program - How to compare random lists?

Tags: python

I'm making a lottery program where playing everyday in a week randomly by (10,1000) people. Every ticket is 6 random numbers between (1,50) For example: [5, 20, 45, 16, 18, 34]. There is one random generated prize ticket.
So I want to compare all the random ticket's number with this prize ticket and have a output like this:
468 people knew 0 out of 6, 351 people knew 1 out of 6, 167 people knew 2 out of 6... etc. Here's my work but im stuck at this point.

```
import random
lucky_number1 = random.sample(range(1, 50), 1)
lucky_number2 = random.sample(range(1, 50), 1)
lucky_number3 = random.sample(range(1, 50), 1)
lucky_number4 = random.sample(range(1, 50), 1)
lucky_number5 = random.sample(range(1, 50), 1)
lucky_number6 = random.sample(range(1, 50), 1)
picked = []
def draw():
    lucky_numbers = [lucky_number1, lucky_number2, lucky_number3, lucky_number4 ,lucky_number5 ,lucky_number6]
    return lucky_numbers
print("Lucky Numbers:", draw())
def play_week():
    totalpeople = 0
    import random
    people = []
    for a in range(0,7):
        a = random.randint(10,100)
        people.append(a)
    print("daily people in a week :" ,people)
    totalpeople = totalpeople + sum(people)
    played_tickets = []
    for i in range(totalpeople):
        n = random.sample(range(1,50), 6)
        played_tickets.append(n)
    print("Number of tickets: " ,len(played_tickets))
    return played_tickets
play_week()

def decide_winners(played_tickets, lucky_numbers):
    right_guesses = [468 ,351 ,167 ,35 ,13 ,2]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

let's look at your code a bit first. `lucky_number1-6` could be replaced by `lucky_numbers = random.sample(range(1,50), 6)` and merged into `draw()` no need for double imports.

```
import random

def draw():
    lucky_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 50), 6)
    return lucky_numbers

def play_week():

    people = []

    for a in range(0,7):
        a = random.randint(10,100)
        people.append(a)

    print("daily people in a week :" ,people)

    totalpeople = sum(people)
    
    played_tickets = []

    for i in range(totalpeople):
        n = random.sample(range(1,50), 6)
        played_tickets.append(n)

    print("Number of tickets: " ,len(played_tickets))
    decide_winners(played_tickets)


def decide_winners(played_tickets):
    lucky_nums = draw()
    right_guesses = [0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0]

    for i in played_tickets:
        match = len(set(i) & set(lucky_nums))

        if match != 0:
            right_guesses[match - 1] += 1
    print(right_guesses)

play_week()
```

When counting numbers you want to draw() first and compare the two lists. Here len(set(A) & set(B)) returns the number of same variables in both lists.